# Image resizing for image gallery on Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm currently working on a web site that will show kind a image gallery on some detail pages. It must show a navigation at the bottom with small thumbnail images and it must show per each element some basic information and the big image.

The big image must be resized too, because there is a maximun size allowed for them.

The point is to use just a source image per multimedia component and being able to resize the images on publishing time so, from the source image would be sent to the client browser a thumbnail and a big image. It's possible to show small and big images using just styles or HTML, but this is quite uneficient because the source (some of them really heavy) image is always sent to the customer.

My first thought was a custom code fragment, something written in C# but I find complicated to resize only some images to a certain size and then resize them again to another size too. I don't find the way to replace the SRC on the final HTML with the appropiate paths neither.

Another idea was to create an old-style PublishBinary method but I find this really complex because looks like the current Tridion architecture is not meant to do this at all...

And the most important point, even in case we can do the resizing succesfully (somehow) it's currently a Tridion 2011 issue to publish twice the same image. Both the big and the small version would came actually from the same multimedia component so shouldn't be possible to publish both of them or playing with the names, the first one would be allways gone, because the path would be updated with the second one :-S.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the Out-of-the-box "Resize Image" Template Building Block? It creates variants of MM components with the specified dimensions, it looks like this is exactly what you need... And Tridion has it since 2008...

Comment: Great question @glezalex - If you are interested in getting more involved with the SDL Tridion community, please consider committing to the SDL Tridion Proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 using your Stack Overflow login so that your accounts are linked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have built an image re-sizing TBB in the past which reads the output of a Dreamweaver or XSLT template. The idea is to produce a tag like the following with the first template.

```
<img src="tcm:1-123" maxWidth="250" maxHeight="400" 
     cropPosition="middle" variantId="250x400" 
     action="PostProcess" enlargeIfTooSmall="true"
/>
```

The "Re-Sizing" TBB then post processes the Output item in the package, looking for nodes with the PostProcess action.

It then creates a variant of the Multimedia Component using the `System.Drawing` library according to the `maxHieght` and `maxWidth` dimention attributes, and publishes it using the `AddBinary()` method @frank mentioned and using the `variantId` attribute for a filename prefix, and variant id (and replaces the SRC attribute with the URL of the new binary).

To make this 100% flexible, if either of the `maxHeight` or `maxWidth` attributes are set to 0, the TBB re-sizes based on just the "non-zero" dimension, or if both are set it crops the image based on the cropPosition attribute. This enables us to make sqare thumbnails for both landscape and portrait images without distorting them. The `enlargeIfTooSmall` attribute is use to prevent small images from being stretched to much.

You can see samples of the final galleries here: http://medicine.yale.edu/web/help/examples/specific/photo/index.aspx

and other image re-sizeing examples here:
http://medicine.yale.edu/web/help/examples/general/images.aspx

All of the images are just uploaded to the CMS once, and then re-sized and cropped on the fly at publish time.

Answer (score 6):

Tridion can perfectly well publish multiple variants on a single MMC. When you call `AddBinary` you can specify that this binary is a variant of the MMC, with each variant being identified by a simple string that you specify.

```
public Binary AddBinary(
    Stream content,
    string filename,
    StructureGroup location,
    string variantId,
    Component relatedComponent,
    string mimeType
)
```

As you can see you can also specify the filename for the binary. If you do, it is your responsibility that variants have unique filenames and filenames between different MMCs remain unique. So typically, it is easiest to simply prefix or suffix the filename with some indication of the variantId: `<MmcImageFileName>_thumbnail.jpg`.

Answer (score 5):

For a recent demo project, I took a completely different approach. The binaries are all published to a broker database. They are extracted from the broker with an HttpModule, which writes the binary data to the file system.
I made it possible to encode the desired width or height in the URL of the image (of course, for binaries that are not images this part of the logic will not work). The module then resizes the image on the fly (truly on the fly, not during publishing!) and writes the resized version to the disk.

For example: if I request /Images/photo.jpg, I will get the original image. If I request /Images/photo_h100.jpg, I get a version of 100 pixels high. The url /Images/photo_w150.jpg leads to a width of 150 pixels.

No variants needed, no republishing because of different size requirements either: resizing is completely done on demand! The performance penalty on the server is negligible: each size is generated only once, until the image is republished.

I used .NET, but of course it can work in Java as well.

Answer (score 4):

Following the Frank's and Quirijn's answer you may be interested on resize the image in a Cartridge Claims processor using the Ambient Data Framework. This solution would be technology agnostic and can be re-used in both Java and .Net. You just need to put the resized image bytes in a Claim and then use it in Java or .Net.

**Java Claims Processor:**

```
public void onRequestStart(ClaimStore claims) throws AmbientDataException {
    int publicationId = getPublicationId();
    int binaryId = getBinaryId();

    BinaryContentDAO bcDAO = (BinaryContentDAO)StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(publicationId, StorageTypeMapping.BINARY_CONTENT);
    BinaryContent binaryContent = bcDAO.findByPrimaryKey(publicationId, binaryId, null);

    byte[] binaryBuff =  binaryContent.getContent();
    pixelRatio = getPixelRatio();

    int resizeWidth = getResizeWidth();

    BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryBuff));
    if (original.getWidth() < MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH) {
        float ratio = (resizeWidth * 1.0f) / (float)MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH; 

        float width =  original.getWidth() * ratio; 
        float height = original.getHeight() * ratio;

        BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(Math.round(width), Math.round(height), original.getType());
        Graphics2D g = resized.createGraphics();
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

        g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, resized.getWidth(), resized.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();

        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        BinaryMeta meta = new BinaryMetaFactory().getMeta(String.format("tcm:%s-%s", publicationId, binaryId));
        String suffix = meta.getPath().substring(meta.getPath().lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

        ImageIO.write(resized, suffix, output);
        binaryBuff = output.toByteArray();
    }
    claims.put(new URI("taf:extensions:claim:resizedimage"), binaryBuff);
}
```

**.Net HTTP Handler:**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    if (context != null) {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        ClaimStore claims = AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore;
        if (claims != null) {
            Codemesh.JuggerNET.byteArray javaArray = claims.Get<Codemesh.JuggerNET.byteArray>("taf:extensions:claim:resizedimage");
            byte[] resizedImage = javaArray.ToNative(javaArray);
            if (resizedImage != null && resizedImage.Length > 0) {
                httpResponse.Expires = -1;
                httpResponse.Flush();
                httpResponse.BinaryWrite(resizedImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Java Filter:**

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {    
        ClaimStore claims = AmbientDataContext.getCurrentClaimStore();
        if (claims != null) {
            Object resizedImage = claims.get(new URI("taf:extensions:claim:resizedimage"));
            if (resizedImage != null) {
                byte[] binaryBuff = (byte[])resizedImage;
                response.getOutputStream().write(binaryBuff);
            }
        }
    }
```